# How to know what UDP port using to send a message

Tags: c#, udp

I have a program that sends a message to a server and the server recognizes the message inteprets it and sends back the message to the port it was listening from in the begining. so let's say the client sends from port 5000. The server will read the message from port 5000, and send back a message to the port the client used to send the message so the client can receive it. My question now is that I don't want to fix a port for the server ( i don't want the server to always send back to client to port 1000), so how can i know what port my client used to send the message every single time? So in my client, my UdpClient Listener = new UdpClient(xxx) [(xxxx) being the port number] can be filled by a new value every single time? the value of the port it used to send the message

thanks

here's my program :

```
private const int sendPort = 9999;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Boolean done = false;
        IPAddress send_to_address = IPAddress.Parse("xx.xxx.xxx.xxx");
        IPEndPoint sending_end_point = new IPEndPoint(send_to_address, sendPort);
        IPEndPoint receiving_end_point = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
        UdpClient Listener = new UdpClient(WHAT TO PUT HERE???);
    while (!done)
    {
        Socket sending_socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        Console.WriteLine("Enter text to send");
        string text_to_send = Console.ReadLine();
        // the socket object must have an array of bytes to send.
        // this loads the string entered by the user into an array of bytes.
        byte[] send_buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text_to_send);

        // Remind the user of where this is going.
        Console.WriteLine("sending to address: {0} port: {1}", sending_end_point.Address, sending_end_point.Port);
        sending_socket.SendTo(send_buffer, sending_end_point);
        Console.WriteLine("Message has been sent to the broadcast address");
        Console.WriteLine("Now we are waiting for a message back from the Listener");

        // here we receive the Message from the Server
        Byte[] ByteFromListener = Listener.Receive(ref receiving_end_point);
        string datafromreceiver = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ByteFromListener);
Console.WriteLine(Datafrom receiver)



        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: every packet has to have 4 chunks of data in it, at minimum. Originating IP and port, and destination IP and port. doesn't matter what port your client decided to use - the server will get that information in the packet headers so it'll know where to send the response to.

Comment: Can't you just use the `IPEndPoint` information?

Comment: I understand, but now the client is listening to the message from the server, how do i know what port i use for the client to recieve back the message?

Comment: @George um, it's the port you choose to assign to the client when you create it. YOU choose the port. And you should be using the `UdpClient` for both sending and receiving, don't create a separate `Socket` for receiving. That way, you receive on the same port that the `UdpClient` is bound to for sending.

Comment: How would it be implemented though? i don't know how to do what you're saying :/

Comment: IP requires a know port number.  You cold instead use UDP multiport and listen at multiport IP address (224 to 239), but multiport address will not normally go through routers.

Comment: Is there no way to figure out what port number I used to send the message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was quite simple. Just needed to use the same socket to receive the message.

Here is the code :

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

class Program
{
    private const int sendPort = 9999;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Boolean done = false;
        IPAddress send_to_address = IPAddress.Parse("10.128.105.177");
        IPEndPoint sending_end_point = new IPEndPoint(send_to_address, sendPort);
        EndPoint receiving_end_point = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
    while (!done)
    {
        Socket sending_socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        Console.WriteLine("Enter text to send");
        string text_to_send = Console.ReadLine();
        // the socket object must have an array of bytes to send.
        // this loads the string entered by the user into an array of bytes.
        byte[] send_buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text_to_send);

        // Remind the user of where this is going.
        Console.WriteLine("sending to address: {0} port: {1}", sending_end_point.Address, sending_end_point.Port);
        sending_socket.SendTo(send_buffer, sending_end_point);
        Console.WriteLine("Message has been sent to the broadcast address");
        Console.WriteLine("Now we are waiting for a message back from the Listener");


        Byte[] ByteFromListener = new byte[8000];
        sending_socket.ReceiveFrom(ByteFromListener, ref receiving_end_point);

        string datafromreceiver;
        datafromreceiver = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ByteFromListener).TrimEnd('\0');          

        //Here we print the message from the server
        Console.WriteLine(datafromreceiver.ToString());



        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hm, yeah, I have the same problem you originally asked about. I want a single application to run 5 servers, each talking to a different client, which listens for the inbound request and responds back to it. But I can't seem to select (or even know) the outbound port used by SendTo, ergo I don't know what the clients are going to get in ReceiveFrom, ergo I don't know where to listen for their replies.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of an oldie and I know you found an answer but I don't think that resolved the original question, which is how to know what port you are sending *from*.

In my case, I wanted a single application, running multiple instances of a UDP class, to talk to multiple connected boxes. The connection box listens for an input, then responds back to whatever it grabbed in its recvfrom.

So I sendTo, it answers back, but I didn't know what it was going to answer back to, unless I know what port sendTo used.

Anyway, the answer was thus:

```
EndPoint ipe = IPEndPoint(targetAddress, targetPort);
sendSocket.Connect(ipe);

// Important part here:
int udpListenPort = ((IPEndPoint)socket.LocalEndPoint).Port;
listenSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(myAddress, udpListenPort);

...
int numBytes = listenSocket.Receive(bytesReceived, bytesReceived.Length, 0);
```

And that works great. The secret sauce is just that *after you connect your outbound socket*, you can see what port it took by looking at the [**socket.LocalEndPoint**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.localendpoint?view=net-7.0) (first recasting it as IPEndPoint), and that's the port you need to bind your listener to -- that is, it is the port that will be seen by the other box in its recvfrom function.